# How do you see your safari search history in finder

Tags: macos, safari

I am looking to restore some safari search history in Time Machine, but is it possible to see the title of the search in finder files? (ex. **Ask Different** | [www.askdifferent.com](http://www.askdifferent.com) the part in bold is what I am looking for)